# I-beam removal from garage ceiling a structural concern?

Tags: walls, framing, ceiling, foundation, contractors

I'm purchasing a cape cod built in 1949 that has only a partial I-beam in basement ceiling.  It appears 10' has been cut and removed from the garage that is under the back of the home. I currently own a very similar cape cod directly across the street that built in 1948 and the I-beam in my home spans the entire width of the foundation so this partial I-beam seems suspicious, additionally it is not a clean cut looks like it was done with a torch.  Is it possible it was built missing 10' in the garage or is it more likely to have been cut to accommodate a larger vehicle?

Comment: That sounds utterly catastrophic. Can you provide pictures?

Comment: I-beams usually mean an important support structure, not usually placed for decoration.  Would have a structural engineer/building inspector(not a house inspector for sales) check it out.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add some pics using the button with "mountains" on it.

Comment: The short answer is that "Yes", removing an I-beam from a ceiling is a structural concern. The long answer will take a licensed engineer to determine how big a concern it is and what the appropriate fix should be.

Answer (score 2):

I beams are an important structural element. It is not likely that the home would be built and have a beam just end with a poor cut.  The likely answer is a homeowner or unknowledgeable worker removed the beam. The only sure way to know if there is an issue is to have an engineer assess the situation. Anything else is conjecture.